# grid manager doesn't place frame in upper left corner

Tags: tkinter, frames, scrollable

I'm debugging a scrollable frame to hold a frame that grows to a larger size, then reduces (contained widgets are destroyed and smaller number placed back).
the frame is :  frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky = 'nw').  However, the smaller frame is placed sort of in the middle of the canvas.  If you run this example, you will initially get a list of 9 check buttons and entries.  If you press the show more button, you will see all 30 buttons/entries,  Then pressing the show less button you will see the original frame, except it will not be in the northwest corner of the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import inspect
import functools
import sys

class ScrollableFrame:
    # https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frame
    def __init__(self,container):
        self.container = container
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(container,height=2)
        self.top_frame.configure(bg='gray15')

    # create a frame to hold the Canvas andscrollbars

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(container,borderwidth=5)
        self.canvas.configure(bg = 'orange')

    #self.canvas.pack_propagate(False)

        self.content_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg = 'yellow')    
    #self.content_frame.grid_propagate(True)
    # create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas 
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set) # again scrollbar.set is a provided function
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient = 'horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set) 
        self.xscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)


    # before we are done we need to put buttons into ScrollableFame, row 0
    # and populate the content_frame with widgets
    # after this has been done, the bounding box must be created 


        container.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

    def finish(self):
        self.container.config(bg = 'lightgreen')
        self.top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=False)
    #self.content_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill = tk.BOTH,expand=False)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nw',ipadx = 5,ipady=5)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.content_frame) 

        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True,ipady=10)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

        self.canvas.pack_propagate(False)

        self.scrollbar.pack(fill='both',side='right',expand='false')
        self.xscrollbar.pack(fill='both',side='bottom',expand='false')
    #self.container.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nsew')
    #self.container.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    #self.container.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)

class DisplayKeys(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs) :
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.keys_ = [f'display{i}' for i in range(30)]
        self._showless = False
        self._checkbuttons_initialized = None
        self.scrollable_frame = ScrollableFrame(parent)
        self._label = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame,
                           text = "Key List",font = LARGE_FONT)
        self._label.grid(column=0,row=0)

        self._sequence = [1,2,3,29,5,7,21,15,6]
        self._showbutton = tk.Button(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame, 
                       text='Show More',
                       command=lambda: 
                       self._showbutton_action())

        self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=10,sticky=tk.N)
        self._update_checkbuttons(
                  self.scrollable_frame.content_frame,self._sequence )
    #self.scrollable_frame.finish()


    def _update_checkbuttons(self,frame,seq):
    #print(*seq)
        if self._checkbuttons_initialized != None :
            for widget in self.scrollable_frame.content_frame.winfo_children() :
                widget.destroy()
        self._checkbuttons_initialized = True     
        self.checkVars = []
        self.txtVars = []
        searchVar = "Search"
        self._checkbuttons = []

        for i,place in enumerate(seq) :
            bv = tk.BooleanVar()
            tvar = tk.StringVar()
            dn = self.keys_[place]
            ck = tk.Checkbutton(frame,text=dn,variable=bv)
            ck.grid(column=0,row=i,sticky='nw')
            self._checkbuttons.append(ck)
            self.checkVars.append(bv)
            txt = tk.Entry(frame,width = 30, textvariable = tvar)
            txt.bind('<Return>',self._cmgo)
            txt.grid(column = 1,row = i,sticky="nw")
        #txt.rowconfigure(0,minsize=400,weight = 1)
        #txt.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
            self.txtVars.append(tvar)
        self.scrollable_frame.finish()
    #self.scrollable_frame.canvas.pack()
    #tk.Label(frame,height=1,bg = 'skyblue').grid(column=0,row=len(seq)+1)
    #self.scrollable_frame.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.scrollable_frame.canvas.bbox("all") ) 

    def _cmgo(self):
        pass

    def _showbutton_action(self):

        if not self._showless :
            self._sequence = range(len(self.keys_))           
            self._showbutton.configure( text = "Show Less")
        #self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=tk.W)
            self._showless = True

        else :            
            self._showbutton.configure(text = "Show More")
        #self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=tk.W)
            self._showless = False
            self._sequence = [1,2,3,29,5,7,21,15,6]


        self._update_checkbuttons(
               self.scrollable_frame.content_frame,self._sequence) 

if __name__=="__main__" :
    LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
    DISPLAY_KEYS_GEOMETRY='350x450'
    root = tk.Tk()
    show = DisplayKeys(root)
    show.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I really understand my example is too large.  I have a workaround which I will show.  It's only virtue is that it shows the value of defining the class, making it easy to destroy and replace the scrollable frame.  The solution is to destroy the entire scrollable frame and rebuild it.  I don't understand why :
self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nw',ipadx = 5,ipady=5)
at line 53 doesn't work, but this workaround will let me move forward.  I apologize if anyone has spent time on this question.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import inspect
import functools
import sys

class ScrollableFrame:
    # https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinter-scrollable-frame
    def __init__(self,container):
        self.container = container
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(container,height=2)
        self.top_frame.configure(bg='gray15')

        # create a frame to hold the Canvas andscrollbars

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(container,borderwidth=5)
        self.canvas.configure(bg = 'orange')

        self.content_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg = 'yellow')    
        #self.content_frame.grid_propagate(True)
        # create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas 
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set) # again scrollbar.set is a provided function
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient = 'horizontal', command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set) 
        self.xscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)


        # before we are done we need to put buttons into ScrollableFame, row 0
        # and populate the content_frame with widgets
        # after this has been done, the bounding box must be created 


        container.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

    def destroy(self):
        self.top_frame.destroy()
        self.canvas.destroy()

    def finish(self):
        self.container.config(bg = 'lightgreen')
        self.top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=False)
        #self.content_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill = tk.BOTH,expand=False)
        self.content_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nw',ipadx = 5,ipady=5)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.content_frame) 
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=False,ipady=10)
        self.scrollbar.pack(fill='both',side='right',expand='false')
        self.xscrollbar.pack(fill='both',side='bottom',expand='false')
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)

class DisplayKeys(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs) :
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.keys_ = [f'display{i}' for i in range(30)]
        self.parent = parent
        self._showless = False
        #self._checkbuttons_initialized = None
        self.scrollable_frame = ScrollableFrame(parent)
        self._label = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame,
                               text = "Key List",font = LARGE_FONT)
        self._label.grid(column=0,row=0)

        self._sequence = [1,2,3,29,5,7,21,15,6]
        self._showbutton = tk.Button(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame, 
                           text='Show More',
                           command=lambda: 
                           self._showbutton_action())

        self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=10,sticky=tk.N)
        self._update_checkbuttons(self.scrollable_frame.content_frame,self._sequence )

    def _update_checkbuttons(self,frame,seq):
        #print(*seq)
    #    self._checkbuttons_initialized = True     
        self.checkVars = []
        self.txtVars = []
        searchVar = "Search"
        self._checkbuttons = []

        for i,place in enumerate(seq) :
            bv = tk.BooleanVar()
            tvar = tk.StringVar()
            dn = self.keys_[place]
            ck = tk.Checkbutton(frame,text=dn,variable=bv)
            ck.grid(column=0,row=i,sticky='w')
            ck.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
            self._checkbuttons.append(ck)
            self.checkVars.append(bv)
            txt = tk.Entry(frame,width = 30, textvariable = tvar)
            txt.bind('<Return>',self._cmgo)
            txt.grid(column = 1,row = i,sticky="nw")
            txt.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=2)
            #txt.grid_rowconfigure(0,minsize=400,weight = 1)
            #txt.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
            self.txtVars.append(tvar)

        self.scrollable_frame.finish()

    def _cmgo(self):
        pass

    def _showbutton_action(self):

        if not self._showless :
            self._sequence = range(len(self.keys_))           
            button_text = "Show Less"
            #self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=tk.W)
            self._showless = True

        else :            
            button_text = "Show More"
            #self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=tk.W)
            self._showless = False
            self._sequence = [1,2,3,29,5,7,21,15,6]

        self.scrollable_frame.destroy()
        self.scrollable_frame = ScrollableFrame(self.parent)
        self._label = tk.Label(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame,
                               text = "Key List",font = LARGE_FONT)
        self._label.grid(column=0,row=0)

        self._showbutton = tk.Button(self.scrollable_frame.top_frame, 
                           text=button_text,
                           command=lambda: 
                           self._showbutton_action())

        self._showbutton.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=10,sticky=tk.N)

        self._update_checkbuttons(self.scrollable_frame.content_frame,self._sequence) 

if __name__=="__main__" :
    LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
    DISPLAY_KEYS_GEOMETRY='350x450'
    root = tk.Tk()
    show = DisplayKeys(root)
    show.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```